# Conflict between spanish babel with memoir in two column and \frontmatter

Tags: memoir, texlive, babel

Consider this simple code compiled with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir} % works without twocolumn
\usepackage[english]{babel} % works in english
\begin{document}
% \frontmatter % Error  "Incomplete \iffalse ...."
foo
% \frontmatter % Error  "Missing \endcsname inserted"
foo
\mainmatter
foo
\end{document}
```

With TeX Live 2021 freshly installed and updated, uncommenting  `\frontmatter` line before or after the first "foo" causes in my computer two different errors, but `\frontmatter` works as expected  (1) working in one column, or (2) removing babel,  or (3) using `english` instead of `spanish` or (4) using TeX Live 2020. I tried to deactivate features for `spanish` babel option (`es-noshorthands`, etc.) with no results.

I guess that this should be a package bug, but for now I am interested in any temporal hack or some workaround as this is stopping me to switch to 2021 in a large project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the twocolumn option of memoir loads the mparhack package which tries to write page numbers to the aux-file. But spanish redefines roman and so in the frontmatter you get errors. You can avoid the redefinition with `es-ucroman`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir} % works without twocolumn
\usepackage[spanish,es-ucroman]{babel} % works in english

\begin{document}
\frontmatter foo
foo
\mainmatter
foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought I tried `es-minimal`,  that include es-ucroman and most of the other Spanish options,  but it should be that I forgot to clean the auxiliary files from a previous test.