# Conflict between babel and memoir using greek and spanish

Tags: memoir, babel, two-column, front-matter, roman-numerals

This is a sequel of [Conflict between spanish babel with memoir in two column and \frontmatter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611747/conflict-between-spanish-babel-with-memoir-in-two-column-and-frontmatter).

Babel In TeXLive 2021 seems to produce now the same error combing these elements also with Greek even without typing anything in greek. Using both then `es-ucroman`is useless. Even using `\pagenumbering{roman}` instead of `\frontmatter` also fails, although there are no error using `\pagenumbering{alph}`.

Minimal not working example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir} % works without twocolumn/memoir
\usepackage[LGR,TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,spanish,es-ucroman]{babel} % works without greek
\begin{document}
% \pagenumbering{roman} % works with `alph` 
\frontmatter % works without frontmatter
foo
\mainmatter
foo
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this problem without switch to another class?

Comment: First off, there's no reason for doing `\pagenumbering{roman}` before `\frontmatter`. Also loading `LGR` and `TS1` is useless.

Comment: spanish is not relevant. The problem is that greek redefines roman and Roman too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Actually also `spanish` is a problem, because it *too* redefines `\roman`.

Comment: @egreg yes but not in this example, as is uses es-ucroman.

Comment: @egreg of course I used `\pagenumbering{roman}` instead of `\frontmatter` not before or after it. I left as comment in the MWE as it seems narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is interaction of `babel-spanish` and `babel-greek` with `mparhack`.

You can fix it by patching the redefinition `mparhack` does to `\@outputdblcol` and the other commands in the package that use `\thepage`.

This should work with the default Roman numbers for Spanish, `es-lcroman` or `es-ucroman` (when `babel-greek` enters the scene).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir} % works without twocolumn/memoir

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,spanish,es-ucroman]{babel} % works without greek
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\def\kernel@roman#1{\romannumeral#1}
\def\kernel@Roman#1{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral#1@}
\def\fix@mph@spanish@greek{%
  \let\es@scroman\@firstofone
  \let\@Roman\kernel@Roman
  \let\@roman\kernel@roman
}
\xpatchcmd{\mph@get@margin}
 {\begingroup}
 {\begingroup\fix@mph@spanish@greek}
 {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@outputdblcol}
 {\def}
 {\fix@mph@spanish@greek\def}
 {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\mph@outputpage@hook}
 {\bgroup}
 {\bgroup\fix@mph@spanish@greek}
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter % works without frontmatter
foo\marginpar{what}

\mainmatter
foo\marginpar{what}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The patch seems to work in a large project without break anything. So perfect, thanks.