# Error \gls@numberpage in Abstract of the document

Tags: errors, glossaries, acronyms, compilation-error, glossaries-extra

I have been trying setup the glossaries and include in all my work but I only have the problem in the **ABSTRACT** because when run the LaTex send the followin the next error. The Abstract is numerate with roman numbers before content list (index), while the rest of the work after index is numerate in basic numbers.

```
<to be read again>
               \gls@numberpage 
l.11 ...t\'ecnicas y econ\'omicas de las \gls{5G} 
                                              para la compartici\'on de ...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
               \gls@numberpage 
l.11 ...de red entre los servicios de \gls{URLLC} 
                                              y \gls{eMBB} / \gls{mMTC} ...
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

**Please, could someone help me? to solve this error.**
**My config is the next.**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{./estilos/estiloBase} 
\usepackage{./estilos/colores}  
\usepackage{./estilos/comandos} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}     
\usepackage{enumitem}           

\usepackage{graphicx,url}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}  
\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage{soul}           

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\usepackage[style=long,sort=def,toc,xindy,acronym,nomain]{glossaries}
\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\color{black}#1} % Cambia el color de las \gls 

\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeglossaries


\newacronym{URLLC}{URLLC}{Comunicaciones ultra confiables de baja latencia - \emph{Ultra Reliable Low Latency Communications}}
\newacronym{5G}{5G}{Redes de Quinta generaci\'on - \emph{Fifth-Generation Networks}}
```

Comment: your code can't be tested but if I should guess: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/611762/2388

Comment: I could solve it. I have added **\usepackage[spanish,english,es-ucroman]{babel}**